# I want to auto refresh seconds in my node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'am currently working on a web app that shows the local time of a giving timezone, i am using a time zone api, i want a way to refresh the page or recall the api every second so i can update the seconds in my page.

I am working with node and express

I did some researchs and found some ways with socket.io but i am asking on some native node methos that can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use JavaScript to refresh the page  every second by using the setInterval function.

```
setInterval(function() {
  window.location.reload();
}, 1000);
```